# VMWare Player 3.1.6 32 bit installed with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, vmware, 32-bit

Dear Ubuntu spezialists,

I use Ubuntu 14.04 on an old 32 bit netbook. Now I installed VMWare 3.1.6, since this is the last real 32bit VMWare Player (although there seem to be newer versions of the Player announced as 32bit versions fo Linux). I could install the 3.1.6 Player but when I start it I get the message:

"VMWare Kernel Module Updater
Before you can run VMWare, several modules must be compiled and loaded into he running kernel.

Kernel Headers 3.13.0-46-generic

Kernel headers for version 3.13.0-46-generic were not found. If you installed them in a non-defaultpath you can specify the path below. Otherwise refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions and click Refresh to search in default locations."

When click the "Browse"-button in the message window the folder usr/src opens and shows the following 4 folders:

- linux-headers-3.13.0.45
- linux-headers-3.13.0.45-generic
- linux-headers-3.13.0.46
- linux-headers-3.13.0.46-generic

Since I am a completly newbie in Linux I would be happy for any hints!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are right: VMWare 3.1.6 is the last real 32bit VMWare Player! This is sad!

Nethertheless I spend some hours to made some changes to the patch 716 of "weltall":

```
diff -r -u source-original/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c source/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c
--- source-original/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c 2012-06-10 01:03:20.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c  2012-06-14 11:28:25.093911963 +0200
@@ -104,7 +104,11 @@
       return actualDentry->d_op->d_revalidate(actualDentry, nd);
    }

-   if (path_lookup(iinfo->name, 0, &actualNd)) {
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 39)
+   if (compat_path_lookup(iinfo->name, 0, &actualNd)) {
+#else
+   if (kern_path(iinfo->name, 0, &(actualNd.path))) {
+#endif
       LOG(4, "DentryOpRevalidate: [%s] no longer exists\n", iinfo->name);
       return 0;
    }
diff -r -u source-original/vmblock-only/linux/filesystem.c source/vmblock-only/linux/filesystem.c
--- source-original/vmblock-only/linux/filesystem.c     2012-06-10 01:03:20.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmblock-only/linux/filesystem.c      2015-03-19 23:32:04.000000000 +0100
@@ -44,9 +44,14 @@
 /* File system operations */

 #if defined(VMW_GETSB_2618)
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 39)
 static int FsOpGetSb(struct file_system_type *fsType, int flags,
                      const char *devName, void *rawData, struct vfsmount *mnt);
 #else
+static struct dentry *FsOpMount(struct file_system_type *fsType, int flags,
+                     const char *devName, void *rawData);
+#endif
+#else
 static struct super_block *FsOpGetSb(struct file_system_type *fsType, int flags,
                                      const char *devName, void *rawData);
 #endif
@@ -66,7 +71,11 @@
 static struct file_system_type fsType = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .name = VMBLOCK_FS_NAME,
+   #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 39)
    .get_sb = FsOpGetSb,
+   #else
+   .mount = FsOpMount,
+   #endif
    .kill_sb = kill_anon_super,
 };

@@ -336,7 +345,11 @@
       goto error_inode;
    }

+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 39)
    if (compat_path_lookup(iinfo->name, 0, &actualNd)) {
+#else
+   if (kern_path(iinfo->name, 0, &(actualNd.path))) {
+#endif
       /*
        * This file does not exist, so we create an inode that doesn't know
        * about its underlying file.  Operations that create files and
@@ -553,7 +566,7 @@
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

-static int
+/*static int
 FsOpGetSb(struct file_system_type *fs_type, // IN: file system type of mount
           int flags,                        // IN: mount flags
           const char *dev_name,             // IN: device mounting on
@@ -561,7 +574,7 @@
           struct vfsmount *mnt)             // IN: vfs mount
 {
    return get_sb_nodev(fs_type, flags, rawData, FsOpReadSuper, mnt);
-}
+}*/
 #else
 /*
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
diff -r -u source-original/vmci-only/linux/driver.c source/vmci-only/linux/driver.c
--- source-original/vmci-only/linux/driver.c    2012-06-10 03:23:58.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmci-only/linux/driver.c 2012-06-14 11:33:13.813197965 +0200
@@ -42,7 +42,6 @@
 #include <linux/miscdevice.h>
 #include <linux/poll.h>
 #include <linux/smp.h>
-#include <linux/smp_lock.h>

 #include "compat_file.h"
 #include "compat_highmem.h"
diff -r -u source-original/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c
--- source-original/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c   2012-06-10 03:23:55.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c    2012-06-14 10:26:33.505000591 +0200
@@ -785,7 +785,7 @@


 #define POLLQUEUE_MAX_TASK 1000
-static spinlock_t pollQueueLock __attribute__((unused)) = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
+static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(pollQueueLock);
 static void *pollQueue[POLLQUEUE_MAX_TASK];
 static unsigned int pollQueueCount = 0;

@@ -1046,7 +1046,8 @@
        * but unfortunately there is no way how to detect that
        * we are building for RedHat's kernel...
        */
-          static spinlock_t timerLock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
+
+          static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(timerLock);

           spin_lock(&timerLock);
           mod_timer(&linuxState.pollTimer, jiffies + 1);
diff -r -u source-original/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c source/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
--- source-original/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c   2012-06-10 03:23:54.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c    2012-06-14 10:35:41.671455630 +0200
@@ -46,7 +46,6 @@
 #include <linux/mman.h>

 #include <linux/smp.h>
-#include <linux/smp_lock.h>

 #include <asm/io.h>
 #include <linux/mc146818rtc.h>
diff -r -u source-original/vmmon-only/linux/iommu.c source/vmmon-only/linux/iommu.c
--- source-original/vmmon-only/linux/iommu.c    2012-06-10 03:23:54.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmmon-only/linux/iommu.c 2012-06-14 10:34:34.493160044 +0200
@@ -35,6 +35,11 @@

 #define PCI_BDF_SLOTFUNC(bdf) PCI_DEVFN(PCI_SLOT(bdf), PCI_FUNC(bdf))
 #define PCI_BDF_BUS(bdf)      (((bdf) >> 8) & 0xff)
+#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 42, 0) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 0, 0)) || LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 2, 0)
+#include <linux/pci.h>
+#define iommu_found() iommu_present(&pci_bus_type)
+#define iommu_domain_alloc() iommu_domain_alloc(&pci_bus_type)
+#endif

 typedef struct PassthruDevice {
    struct pci_dev *pdev;
@@ -44,7 +49,7 @@


 static LIST_HEAD(passthruDeviceList);
-static spinlock_t passthruDeviceListLock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
+static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(passthruDeviceListLock);
 static void *pciHolePage = NULL;

 /*
diff -r -u source-original/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h source/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h
--- source-original/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h   2012-06-10 03:23:56.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h    2012-06-14 11:04:48.318105972 +0200
@@ -47,6 +47,20 @@
 #   define net_device device
 #endif

+/* it looks like these have been removed from the kernel 3.1
+ * probably because the "transition" is considered complete.
+ * so to keep this source compatible we just redefine them like they were
+ * previously
+ */
+#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 41, 0) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 0, 0)) || LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 1, 0)
+#define HAVE_ALLOC_NETDEV      /* feature macro: alloc_xxxdev
+                      functions are available. */
+#define HAVE_FREE_NETDEV       /* free_netdev() */
+#define HAVE_NETDEV_PRIV       /* netdev_priv() */
+#define HAVE_NETIF_QUEUE
+#define HAVE_NET_DEVICE_OPS
+#endif
+

 /*
  * SET_MODULE_OWNER appeared sometime during 2.3.x. It was setting
diff -r -u source-original/vmnet-only/driver.c source/vmnet-only/driver.c
--- source-original/vmnet-only/driver.c 2012-06-10 03:23:56.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmnet-only/driver.c  2012-06-14 10:44:17.628702772 +0200
@@ -28,7 +28,6 @@
 #include <linux/poll.h>

 #include <linux/smp.h>
-#include <linux/smp_lock.h>

 #include <linux/netdevice.h>
 #include <linux/etherdevice.h>
@@ -105,7 +104,7 @@
  * not have vnetStructureMutex already acquired,
  * it is most certainly a bug.
  */
-static rwlock_t vnetPeerLock = RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
+static DEFINE_RWLOCK(vnetPeerLock);

 /*
  * All concurrent changes to the network structure are
@@ -115,6 +114,7 @@
  * vnetStructureMutex and vnetPeerLock for write.
  */
 compat_define_mutex(vnetStructureMutex);
+compat_define_mutex(vnetMutex);

 #if defined(VM_X86_64) && !defined(HAVE_COMPAT_IOCTL)
 /*
@@ -264,11 +264,11 @@
                struct file * filp)  // IN:
 {
    int ret = -ENOTTY;
-   lock_kernel();
+   compat_mutex_lock(&vnetMutex);
    if (filp && filp->f_op && filp->f_op->ioctl == VNetFileOpIoctl) {
       ret = VNetFileOpIoctl(filp->f_dentry->d_inode, filp, iocmd, ioarg);
    }
-   unlock_kernel();
+   compat_mutex_unlock(&vnetMutex);
    return ret;
 }

@@ -1134,9 +1134,9 @@
    if (filp && filp->f_dentry) {
       inode = filp->f_dentry->d_inode;
    }
-   lock_kernel();
+   compat_mutex_lock(&vnetMutex);
    err = VNetFileOpIoctl(inode, filp, iocmd, ioarg);
-   unlock_kernel();
+   compat_mutex_unlock(&vnetMutex);
    return err;
 }
 #endif
diff -r -u source-original/vmnet-only/filter.c source/vmnet-only/filter.c
--- source-original/vmnet-only/filter.c 2012-06-10 03:23:55.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmnet-only/filter.c  2012-06-14 11:07:27.433702814 +0200
@@ -40,6 +40,9 @@
 #include "vnetFilterInt.h"
 #include "vnetInt.h"
 #include "vmnetInt.h"
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 2, 0)
+#include <linux/export.h>
+#endif

 // VNet_FilterLogPacket.action for dropped packets
 #define VNET_FILTER_ACTION_DRP         (1)
@@ -85,7 +88,7 @@
  * callbacks can be concurrently executing on multiple threads on multiple
  * CPUs, so we should revisit locking for allowing for that in the future.
  */
-spinlock_t activeRuleLock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
+DEFINE_SPINLOCK(activeRuleLock);

 /*
  * Logging.
diff -r -u source-original/vmnet-only/hub.c source/vmnet-only/hub.c
--- source-original/vmnet-only/hub.c    2012-06-10 03:23:55.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmnet-only/hub.c 2012-06-14 10:46:12.983201426 +0200
@@ -81,7 +81,7 @@
  * so we use __attribute__((unused)) to quiet the compiler.
  */

-static spinlock_t vnetHubLock __attribute__((unused)) = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
+static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(vnetHubLock);


 /*
diff -r -u source-original/vmnet-only/netif.c source/vmnet-only/netif.c
--- source-original/vmnet-only/netif.c  2012-06-10 03:23:55.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmnet-only/netif.c   2012-06-14 10:58:15.294677818 +0200
@@ -62,7 +62,9 @@
 static int  VNetNetifStartXmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev);
 static struct net_device_stats *VNetNetifGetStats(struct net_device *dev);
 static int  VNetNetifSetMAC(struct net_device *dev, void *addr);
+#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 42, 0) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 0, 0)) || LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 2, 0)
 static void VNetNetifSetMulticast(struct net_device *dev);
+#endif
 #if 0
 static void VNetNetifTxTimeout(struct net_device *dev);
 #endif
@@ -131,7 +133,9 @@
       .ndo_stop = VNetNetifClose,
       .ndo_get_stats = VNetNetifGetStats,
       .ndo_set_mac_address = VNetNetifSetMAC,
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 2, 0)
       .ndo_set_multicast_list = VNetNetifSetMulticast,
+#endif
       /*
        * We cannot stuck... If someone will report problems under
        * low memory conditions or some such, we should enable it.
@@ -620,11 +624,12 @@
  *
  *----------------------------------------------------------------------
  */
-
+#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 42, 0) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 0, 0)) || LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 2, 0)
 void
 VNetNetifSetMulticast(struct net_device *dev) // IN: unused
 {
 }
+#endif


 /*
diff -r -u source-original/vmnet-only/userif.c source/vmnet-only/userif.c
--- source-original/vmnet-only/userif.c 2012-06-10 03:23:55.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vmnet-only/userif.c  2012-06-14 10:53:49.212819374 +0200
@@ -572,10 +572,19 @@
     unsigned int tmpCsum;
     const void *vaddr;

-    vaddr = kmap(frag->page);
-    tmpCsum = csum_and_copy_to_user(vaddr + frag->page_offset,
-                    curr, frag->size, 0, &err);
-    kunmap(frag->page);
+#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 42, 0) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 0, 0)) || LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 2, 0)
+vaddr = kmap(skb_frag_page(frag));
+#else
+vaddr = kmap(frag->page);
+#endif
+tmpCsum = csum_and_copy_to_user(vaddr + frag->page_offset,
+curr, frag->size, 0, &err);
+#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 42, 0) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 0, 0)) || LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 2, 0)
+kunmap(skb_frag_page(frag));
+#else
+kunmap(frag->page);
+#endif
+
     if (err) {
        return err;
     }
diff -r -u source-original/vsock-only/linux/af_vsock.c source/vsock-only/linux/af_vsock.c
--- source-original/vsock-only/linux/af_vsock.c 2012-06-10 01:03:21.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vsock-only/linux/af_vsock.c  2012-06-14 11:36:10.596974749 +0200
@@ -102,7 +102,6 @@
 #include <linux/miscdevice.h>
 #include <linux/poll.h>
 #include <linux/smp.h>
-#include <linux/smp_lock.h>
 #include <asm/io.h>
 #if defined(__x86_64__) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 12)
 #   if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 0)
diff -r -u source-original/vsock-only/linux/util.c source/vsock-only/linux/util.c
--- source-original/vsock-only/linux/util.c 2012-06-10 01:03:21.000000000 +0200
+++ source/vsock-only/linux/util.c  2012-06-14 11:36:48.302138890 +0200
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@
 struct list_head vsockBindTable[VSOCK_HASH_SIZE + 1];
 struct list_head vsockConnectedTable[VSOCK_HASH_SIZE];

-spinlock_t vsockTableLock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
+DEFINE_SPINLOCK(vsockTableLock);

 /*
  * snprintf() wasn't exported until 2.4.10: fall back on sprintf in those
```

Booting the computer you have to use "Shift" in order to choose Kernel 3.2!!!
If you use the original "patch-modules_3.4.0" and my modified module it should work for you, too.

It would be great, if you even find a solution for Kernel 3.13!

Good luck,
Claus